# Export Multiple Query Results to Single Excel File

Tags: sql, excel, ssms, export-to-excel

I ran a sp in SSMS and it gathers information from 50+ databases with the exact same structure.  I am pulling results such as CustomerName, NumberOfUsers and VersionofCode.  When I execute the procedure, I get 50+ different result sets, all with the same columns selected.  Instead of exporting these 50+ times and putting it together in a single excel sheet, I'd like to see if I can export all results to 1 excel file.

Is this possible?  I would have to think there would be a way to do this as my column names match up for every database I am querying.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a number of ways to solve this problem.  I would address the issue by attempting to merge the many result sets from your stored procedure calls into a single result set and then perform whatever output-export (to excel) that you wish to do.

Simplest method would be to use a temp table to accumulate the results from each stored proc call.  You can use the "INSERT #temptable EXEC mystoredproc @param1" syntax to store the results of a stored proc.

Here's a little example I whipped up:

```
-- *** Create a sample stored proc that returns one result set ***
CREATE PROC spGetCompanyEmployees @pCompanyID AS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Company.CompanyName
        , Department.DepartmentName 
        , Employee.EmployeeName
    FROM Company 
        LEFT JOIN Department ON Department.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        LEFT JOIN Employee ON Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID
    WHERE Company.CompanyID = @pCompanyID
END
GO


-- *** Demonstrate how to call that stored proc multiple times, 
-- *** accumulating the results in a temp table and selecting
-- *** the combined results at the end.

CREATE TABLE #ttbl
(
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(60)
    , DepartmentName NVARCHAR(60)
    , EmployeeName NVARCHAR(60)
)

INSERT  #ttbl
  EXEC spGetCompanyEmployees 1

INSERT  #ttbl
  EXEC spGetCompanyEmployees 2

SELECT * FROM #ttbl
```

The resulting output from that final SELECT will be a combined, single result set from both stored procedure calls.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I combined the suggestion to use a temp table with an example from [this blog post](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/search-and-find-table-by-name) that uses sys.sp_msforeachdb to iterate through databases, resulting in the following:

```
Create TABLE #temp
(
    DbName NVARCHAR(50),
    TableName NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT #temp

EXEC
    sys.sp_msforeachdb 
    'SELECT ''?'' DatabaseName, Name FROM [?].sys.Tables WHERE Name LIKE ''%sometablename%'''

Select * from #temp
```